# How to assert java exception in web driver which is displaying through jsp in java?

Tags: java, jsp, selenium-webdriver

I want to assert the exception message in web driver, i display the exception message through jsp like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">       
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>     
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.PrintWriter" %>      

<html>      
<head>    
<title>Online Accounting Software</title>     
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />    
</head>     
<body>     

  <div class="wrapper">    
<div class="page-container">     
    <jsp:include page="/header.jsp" />    
    <jsp:include page="/mainMenuHeader.jsp" />     
 <div class="blocktenant">    
  <%     
      // unwrap ServletExceptions.    
      while (exception instanceof ServletException) {      
        exception = ((ServletException) exception).getRootCause();    
      }

      // print stack trace.     
      out.println(exception.getMessage());    
  %>   
  </div>   
  </div>     
</div>    

</body></html>
```

But i am not able to assert for the exception message by using driver.getPageSource().contains(containString); and my message is "com.veersoft.gwt.shared.VsException: Name 'alice bob' already exists.  Provide different name"

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks,
MSNaidu..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to catch directly the message like :

```
String t = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.page-container div.blocktenant")).getText();

Assert.assertEquals(t,message);
```

have you the rendenring in html ? like what the browser displays.